# how to fix org.scala-js#sbt-scalajs;0.6.2: not found

Tags: scala.js

It's my first time to try the Tutorial.

It seems that I miss some repository.

The error is:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-js#sbt-scalajs;0.6.2
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-js/sbt-scalajs/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/0.6.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-js/sbt-scalajs/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/0.6.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\fairj_000\.ivy2\local\org.scala-js\sbt-scalajs\scala_2.11\sbt_0.13\0.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\fairj_000\.ivy2\org.scala-js\sbt-scalajs\0.6.2\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== oschina nexus: tried
[warn]   http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-public: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype release: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/scala-js/sbt-scalajs_2.11_0.13/0.6.2/sbt-scalajs-0.6.2.pom
```

and here is my `project/plugin.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.2")
```

build.sbt:

```
name := """scalajstest"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
```

build.properties:

```
#Activator-generated Properties
#Mon Apr 13 01:08:48 CST 2015
template.uuid=d9b4f0bf-a417-4065-80af-1184e996ed95
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

Should I add extra repository and what is it?

Comment: Hum, the logs show that it's trying to resolve sbt-scalajs for Scala 2.11 instead of 2.10, which does exist because it is an sbt plugin. Apparently it's thinking it should use Scala 2.11 to compile the build, which is not good. Do you have any other file in `project/`?

Comment: @sjrd I got it.I have add `global.sbt` to `~/.sbt/0.13`.add content `scalaVersion := "2.11.6"` to change the default `2.10.4`(I didn't install scala but just sbt,so it's annoying I use `sbt console` the default is not the latest.). I commented this line and then it works well.Thx for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resume the discussion in the comments:

**TL;DR:** Remove `scalaVersion := "2.11.x"` from  the global sbt config.

The OP had a `scalaVersion := "2.11.6"` in his global sbt configuration. This caused the build itself to be compiled with Scala 2.11.

However, sbt currently compiles with Scala 2.10 and the relevant artifacts are only published for Scala 2.10. Hence the lookup for the Scala.js sbt-plugin compiled for Scala 2.11 failed.